# jquery slidetoggle hide previous element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a slideToggle function on click, I want to hide the previous element that was clicked when a new one is clicked, I've used this same set of code previously and its worked however it's no longer working now and I'm stumped at why its no longer works:

My code is as below or view a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H8LLs/2/)

js/js.js

```
$('.togglesources').hide();
$('.captionsource').on('click', function () {
            $(this).next('.togglesources').slideToggle();
            $(this).parent().siblings().children().next().slideUp();
                      return false;
        });
```

index.html

```
<div class="mostpopular">
             <h4>Nokia:</h4>
             <h5>3100</h5>
            <p>Most popular mobile phone of the year</p>
                <div class="sources">
                    <p class="captionsource">Click to toggle source</p>
                        <div class="togglesources">
                            <p class="source"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_best-selling_mobile_phones#2003">Wikipedia (Data Source)</a></p>
                            <p class="source"><a href="http://gsmsolution24.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/nokia-3100-3120-6100-hardware-repair.html" target="_blank">GSM Solution (Image Source)</a></p>
                        </div><!-- End Toggle Sources -->
                </div><!-- End Sources -->
        </div>
        <!-- END MOST POP -->
        <div class="mostpopular">

             <h4>Lord of the Rings:</h4>
             <h5>Return of the King</h5>
                <p>Highest Grossing Film</p>
                <div class="sources">
                    <p class="captionsource">Click to toggle source</p>
                    <div class="togglesources">
                         <p class="source"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_highest-grossing_films#High-grossing_films_by_year" target="_blank">Wikipedia</a></p>
                     <p class="source"><a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0167260/" target="_blank">IMDB (Image Source)</a></p>
                        </div> <!-- End Toggle Sources -->
                </div> <!-- End Sources -->

        </div>
```

would appreciate some help in regards to this.

Why aren't the other '.togglesources' divs closing when I open a new one?

Comment: Fiddle is Working fine

Comment: @ling.s its not hiding the previous source

Comment: Previous source means what?

Comment: @ling.s He wants to close all the other .togglesources divs that he's opened. In other words if you click on the first "Click to toggle source" and then the second "Click to toggle source" the first sources div should close while the second one opens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $('.togglesources').hide();
    $('.captionsource').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('.mostpopular').siblings().find('.togglesources').slideUp();
            $(this).next('.togglesources').slideToggle();
            $(this).parent().siblings().children().next().slideUp();
    return false;
        });
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H8LLs/3/)**

Comment: thanks that worked exactly how I wanted it to. Is there a particular reason as to why my example wasn't working as expected?

Comment: There was no code for hiding other toggling elements if they are already shown. in above code we ensure that all other toggling elemets gets slideup except the one on which you have clicked,